# How to get the first value of last row of a CSV file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How can i get the values of the 'Number' field of last row of the csv file

```
Number, Product, Year
1,JK,2016,
2,TL,2016,
3,HNK,2016,
```

in this case the value 3 so that i can store the value of three to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use python only :

```
with open('csv_file.csv','r') as f:
    opened_file = f.readlines()
    var = opened_file[-1].split(',')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load your `csv` file into a `pandas` `DataFrame` and read the last row from it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file.csv')
last_number = df['Number'].values[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.read_csv("test1.csv").iloc[-1]["Number"])    # Prints 3
```